# How to link two tables in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables as below:

**Table-1-contacts

 -id (primary key, AUTO_INCREMENT)

 -firstname(varchar)

 -lastname (varchar)

 -email (varchar)**

**Table-2-comments

 -id (primary key, AUTO_INCREMENT)

 -fullname (varchar)

 -email (varchar)

 -comment(text) 

 -date(varchar)**

I want to write php and MySQL query to get and write comments which will be connected to the contact.I want to to get output as below:

**url-contact.php?id=1

name-contact1

comment-contact1 is great.**

**url-contact.php?id=2

name-contact2

comment-contact2 is okay.**

How can i do this? First I need to write comments which will be connected to each contact when entering from that contacts page. Second I need to get all the comments of that contact when that contact is accessed.

I appreciate the help from you now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: how are the two tables related?

Comment: i want to write comments on each contact. Now I have a working comment system. My doubt is how to link/connect it to each contact so that it will be unique. Many thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 1):

You should design your database schema so that the two tables have a natural join. e.g. every comment should have a contact_id which is the id of the contact who posted it. Then you can do things like

select * from comment where comment.contact_id = (insert contact_id here)

You can't use contact name, because what if two contacts have the same name? (This happens very frequently on Facebook, for example)

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. Just to clarify I have to add an extra field in comments table as 'contact_id'.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your tables already have data in them, the best I can imagine doing is to select it based upon the email.

In order to complete this, do a SELECT email FROM contacts WHERE id='id'. Then using the return from that, then SELECT * FROM comments WHERE email='email' in order to retrieve all the associated comments.

The only thing you would need to watch out for is empty email values, in which case you most likely will need to redesign your approach using the answer suggested by Patashu.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. My tables are empty, actually I am building that system so any alterations can be made. Please let me know if you know any better options.

Comment: How are the values for the table `contacts` populated?

Comment: function SaveContact ($post)
{
 $conn = GetConnection();
 
 $query = "insert into contacts (contactowner, prefix, fname, lname, email, phone, mobile, reportsto, mailingstreet, mailingcity, mailingstate, mailingzip, mailingcountry, otherstreet, othercity, otherstate, otherzip, othercountry, fax, homephone, otherphone, assistant, asstphone, discription, leadsource, birthdate, department, catid) values( '".$post['contactowner']."', '".$post['prefix']."', "."'".$post['fname']."',.......etc.

Comment: Hmm... From what I have been able to understand, the best way to associate comments would be to force a user to enter their email as a way to associate contacts and comments. Otherwise, you would need to have a login system to identify users.

**Otherwise**, you could try a simpler approach by setting a cookie, however this method has many holes as you can imagine with varying browsers, clearing cookies, etc.

Comment: Thanks 'iWizardPro'. Actually this is a CRM and users are giving comments to their clients. users have a login but what i need to achieve is linking the comment with each contact. Any new thoughts do let me know.

Comment: Wait, would you clarify? So, how exactly do the clients fall into this situation? Who are the clients and who are the users?

Comment: Table contacts are for clients. Users will have a login before accessing contacts.

Comment: Umm... There is no simple method unless you have the contacts identified using a unique value such as their email address. Or else the clients will require a way to login to be associated with their contact information.